# Why use linux, and which one should I use?

Tags: linux, windows

maybe this question may seem a little bit odd here, but I would like to ask it to people that actually got some knowledge and use this system.

Should I use linux? If so, which one would you consider best, and why?

I'm currently using win 7 64-bit. On my PC, I mainly play some games(like SC2, DayZ, and some other games, from steam), search web, listen to music, and I'm learning C++.

I know many people use Linux, but I'm not sure why and if it's good for me. Is there anything superior to Windows, except for price?

Comment: Linux may be helpful for your `c++` learning, but it won't be a replacement for a gaming platform.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it is. Linux is Free and Open source, so it's free and you can have the source code also. If you're learning C++ or C what ever you will feel more comfortable when using Linux. Because lot of developer in the world using linux. There are lot of features to do programming with Linux than Windows. And I don't have any experience with Stream yet(Don't have time to play.. :'( )
But I'm sure every game that you're playing with Stream in Windows, you can play them with Stream in Linux also.
Internet surfing, Listing Music are common function of any OS. So you don't have to worry about those thing, with Linux system you may feel more safer while surfing internet than Windows. Because lot of viruses are wrote to attack Windows system. I'm not telling Linux is totally virus free, but with Linux you don't have to worry about Viruses. If anything happen to your Linux system. You can fix it.
Anyway I suggest you to try Ubuntu or Linux Mint as your first Linux experience.
because they are more user-friendly. Linux Mint has lot similarities with Windows. You won't feel any uncomfortable.
So, you don't have to think twice. Just do it. Feel the free.
May FOSS be with you!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is mostly in the license of the software, for many this is a important thing. The license used for Linux and most software that runs on Linux gives the user more freedom. While Windows is very restricted by Microsoft and have built in features that users don't want or need.

For more information about freedom see:
http://www.fsf.org/

Google Windows 7 sins to find more about whats not so good about windows 7. (link limit)

The problem for gamers are that many games are made to run on Windows only. You can make them run in Linux sometimes but with a bit of work (with wine). Also most of these these games does not have this free license.

You can see my answer about running 'Windows games' in Linux at:
http://www.linux.com/learn/answers/view/706-windows-games-on-linux (I'm Aron)

The license used for Linux and most Linux software also require the software to be open source so there are no secrets about what the software does or how it works. It's is not required to be cost free, but most of the time it is.

Linux also distributes software in software repositorys, and that is a major feature to avoid that users manual download and install malware from random sites online. Also to have 20 000+ programs easy available is awesome.